# Is there a dual to "non-sequitur"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms

A non sequitur:

> "a conclusion or statement that does not logically follow from the previous argument or statement."
>
> "A non sequitur is a conversational literary device, often used for comedic purposes. It is something said that, because of its apparent lack of meaning relative to what preceded it, seems absurd to the point of being humorous or confusing."

I've heard many examples of this throughout my life, but I've also heard many examples of a 'dual' to this: when one is in a group of friends, or perhaps in 'polite company', and someone says something strikingly weird that maybe tangentially relates to the conversation but immediately stops the conversation because no one knows how to continue; not a case of not following *from* anything, but that there is nothing that can follow from it. Everyone (but the speaker) is secretly baffled and we try to change the subject or just delicately 'step past' the comment.

I say this is 'dual' to being a non sequitur because it arises in the same scenarios and has a similar effect, but instead of considering the past (from which it failed to follow), the direction of the time is reversed - almost, if one were to rewind the conversation in reverse, this [thing] would become a non sequitur and an ordinary non sequitur would become an example of [this thing].

Does anyone know a good word or phrase for this [thing] I am trying to describe?

P.S. No I do not mean 'outrageous' or something similar to that: the focus is on absurdity rather than shock; the conversation comes to a brief standstill not out of strong emotion but out of confusion, or second-hand embarrassment.

Unfortunately no specific example comes to mind that I can repeat here. I must emphasise again, I would like to define this as how a non-sequitur is defined *but with the time reversed*.

Comment: Without an example, we can't tell what you're talking about. The description doesn't bring to mind any common situations. Data is better than theoretical description.

Answer (score 2):

Non-praeceditur? Something that does not, cannot go before in order of time?

The riddle "what's the difference between a duck?" could be understood as a non-praeceditur and the humour of the answer "one of its legs is both the same" stems partly from the bubbling absurdity of it being a non-sequitur in impossible relation to a non-praeceditur...

Comment: Hello, BP. Is this an actual English word? ELU deals with usage, and DIY suggestions are considered off-topic.

Comment: Hello EA, it's a fair challenge but of course it's a Latin word and so the question needs to shift to the adjacent question, whether a non-praeceditur is a usage recognisably assimilated into the English language - to which the answer has to be a resounding 'nope'. I just felt FShrike's question opened the possibility or, erm, sequitur if you will, that maybe there should be such a word. In the same way that we have to use Schwellenangst because there's no word in English (as there should be, for such an English experience) for the anxiety in and of the threshold...

Answer (score 2):

Cambridge Dictionaries list **conversation-stopper**, defined as "a remark that stops the natural flow of the conversation because it is unexpected and in some way causes embarrassment or shock". (Source: [*Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conversation-stopper).)

Their example sentence is: *When she told us her son was in prison, it was a real conversation-stopper.*

Macmillan has a similar definition, although they don't hyphenate: [conversation stopper](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/conversation-stopper).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I was looking to avoid words or phrases which are shock-related. As explained, it should be as weird, or baffling, as a non-sequitur, the only difference being in the time flow (instead of it not following from anything, nothing follows from it)